# GraphQl does not return CMS page having CMS block

Tags: magento2, cms-pages, graphql

I have created CMS Page which have custom CMS block.

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Vendor_Test::cms/vendortest.phtml"}}
```

This CMS Page gets reflected correctly at the magento frontend with all the content alongwith cms block. But GraphQl returns error.

```
Error filtering template: Invalid template file: 'Vendor_Test::cms/vendortest.phtml' in module: '' block's name: 'magento\\framework\\view\\element\\template_0
```

Is this core bug ? Or am I missing something ? I can't find anything related to this in magento forum.

Comment: did you get the solution? Did GraphQl return the content of vendortest.phtml in responce.

Comment: yes, it gave correctly, it was minor syntax issue from my end.

Comment: can you share in detail